# How to get json property content

Tags: json, wso2

I use a property to save my json payload

```
<property expression="json-eval($.)" name="req_json" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

The json content as below:

```
{ "schema": { "computerName": "PC243854", "ipAddress": "11.2.45.120"}, "data": { "code": "ZFIR006", "filters":[{ "dataType": "integer", "fieldName": "TEST", "operator": "=", "values": ["1","9"] } ], "schema":1} }
```

I want to use the "req_json" property to get json content value of filters,how can I do?

```
[{ "dataType": "integer", "fieldName": "TEST", "operator": "=", "values": ["1","9"] } ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is it mandatory for you to get it from req_json property? You could get it easier from the payload and store it in another property like that

```
<property expression="json-eval($.data.filters)" name="req_filters" scope="default"/>
```

You can get more sample of json manipulation here : https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/JSON+Support